# Visual Studio 2015 losing settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio 2015 (RTM) keeps resetting some of my tweaks each time I reopen it (for example Automatic brace completion).

I'm running it in administrator mode and tried **devenv /resetsettings** and reinstalling but that did not help.

Any ideas how to fix this will be appreciated.

Comment: What sort of environment are you working in? Is this a work computer or your personal one?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 introduced synchronising settings across multiple machines, see menu => **Tools** => **Options** => **Environment** => **Synchronising Settings**. Might settings on another computer be taking precedence?

Comment: @kingfrito_5005 It is a work computer, but i'm using local admin account.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I tried that and nothing changed.

So far the settings that keep switching to defaults are:
Automatic brace completion
Keyboard shortcuts
Find in files also insists it will search in *.cs

Answer (score 5):

This has been fixed in [KB3165756](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx) and the update instructions are found on the same page.

Comment: The KB says this is fixed in VS2015 Update 3. I've got Update 3, and my custom settings get wiped quite frequently. Maybe it's the Windows 10 update problem, or maybe not. I'm so sick of this crap.

Comment: Bookmarks, Breakpoints, Tools-Options getting reset. This update too  didn't help.

Comment: Same here. I have the update 3 installed, that KB is installed, and my settings keep getting wiped. Windows 8.1 here. So annoying.