# Visual Studio 2015 Word Wrap keeps getting reset to indeterminate automatically

Tags: visual-studio-2015, word-wrap

For as long as I can remember, the Word Wrap option in VS 2015 would reset itself to "indeterminate" state after a while. I'm referring to the Word Wrap option for All Languages (Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General). I would manually check the checkbox and that would turn on Word Wrap for all files in VS, but after a while (hours later), I notice the files I'm working with no longer have Word Wrap turned on, and this checkbox would be reset by itself to the indeterminate state (filled checkbox).

Anyone else ran into this issue, and know how to get it to stick?

Comment: My best guess would by that you are accidently toggling the word wrap using the keyboard shortcut. To test this hypothesis go in Options, Keyboard and remove all the keyboard shortcuts for ToggleWordWrap. Try it for a few hours/days and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Gilles thank you for the suggestion. I am pretty sure this is not the case b/c I know I haven't used any keyboard shortcuts in VS in the last few hours, and it has already gotten reset.

Comment: are you using VS at all during this test which it is reset or are you using it without using shortcuts? I can think of 3 possible causes: some process is overwriting the settings file, a bug in VS or you are accidentally hitting the toggle word wrap shortcut. One last thing is VS crashing? Because when it does changes in settings are often lost if they haven't been saved.

Comment: I was using VS without using any keyboard shortcuts when it got reset by itself. I think it's very possible some other process overwrote the setting or a bug in VS. I have ReSharper installed so it's possible RerSharper might be overwriting it. VS has not crashed when this happened so it's not that.

Comment: I would still try unmapping the keyboard shortcut just in case. Won't cost you anything to try and it's not like you are using this shortcut anyway. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832504/visual-studio-2015-losing-settings. And : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767180/visual-studio-2012-loses-settings-when-i-open-multiple-instances