# How to keep word wrap (and other) settings in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, I prefer to keep word wrap on since I do a lot of work on multiple files at a time so I keep 2 documents stacked side-by-side most of the time.

Horizontal scrolling, therefore, is not only inconvenient and annoying, but also confusing, so I turn word wrap on.

In my settings, I have it enabled for all languages (and in the specific settings for every language as well) but it doesn't seem to actually happen unless I go to **Edit > Advanced > Word Wrap**

[image]

Is there a config file or registry entry that I can edit so that Word Wrap stays a thing permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible scenarios for VS resetting word wrap:

1. You are accidentally pressing the shortuct <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. 
   [How can I toggle word wrap in Visual Studio.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315485/how-can-i-toggle-word-wrap-in-visual-studio-net)
2. You are missing Visual Studio fix KB3165756.
   [Visual Studio 2015 losing settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832504/visual-studio-2015-losing-settings)